# Recursive Function - Compare 2 lists, return the elements that don't exist in both

Tags: python

I have to do a RECURSIVE FUNCTION, comparing two lists and returning the elements that they don't have in common.

This is what I have so far:

```
def compare(list1, list2):
    if list2[0] in list1:
        list1.remove(list2[0])
        return compare(list1[1:], list2[1:])

    return list1  

#Example 
 >>>>compare([2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3])
 [4, 5]
```

I can compare if the first element of the list (list[0]) is the same but I am having trouble on how to compare the elements if they are not in the first position...I've tried many options but I'm a begginer in programming and don't really know how to do it. It must be a RECURSIVE FUNCTION, I can't use FOR or WHILE. And is there any way that I can do it without using remove()? Thank you so much

Comment: What if the first list is `[1,2,3,4,4,4,4,5]`? Do you expect `[4,4,4,4,5]` or `[4,5]`?

Comment: The first list [2, 3, 4, 5] second [2, 3] and i must return  [4, 5]

Comment: But I asked a different question. What if the first list has duplicates?

Comment: @KellyBaptista What if the first list is `[1,2,3,4,4,4,4,5]` and the second list is `[2, 3]`?

Comment: Oh sorry, Yes I expect [1,4,4,4,4,5]

Comment: @KellyBaptista Is the "recursive" part mandatory?

Comment: @nandukk yes, that's the part that's difficult to me :(

Comment: From the popular Stack Overflow category: things you should not do recursively done recursively.

Comment: @KlausD. Tell that to my teacher :|

Comment: @KellyBaptista would you post the version your teacher shows you when you get it? I'm curious to know if he found a *nice* way to do this.

Comment: @Griffon26 I will

Comment: Because I kind of spoiled the exercise let me tell you one thing about recursion. In your code you removed the first element from the list before calling the same function again. The point in recursion is that you don't have to do that; passing list2[1:] when you call the function recursively means that when you enter that function the parameter list2 is now what you passed to the function, so everything except the first entry. In recursion you often don't modify a sequence in place, you pass a subsection to the inner call. To that inner call that subsection is the entire sequence.

Comment: @Griffon26 thank you for explanning that for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative answer. It has less duplication at the cost of a dirty trick to stay within the rules of the exercise:

```py
def compare(a, b):
    if isinstance(b, list):
        # Let's cheat and change the meaning of the parameters.
        return compare(a, set(b)) + compare(b, set(a))
    else:
        result = []

        if a:
            if a[0] not in b:
                result.append(a[0])

            result.extend(compare(a[1:], b))

        return result
```

In your code you removed the first element from the list before calling the same function again. That's not necessary when you use recursion, it deals with that in a different way. In recursion you often don't modify a sequence in place, you pass a subsection to the inner call. To that inner call that subsection is the entire sequence.

Comment: I simplified it a little. Now with **even more** recursion =)

Comment: You can eliminate the "dirty trick" (`isinstance`) by creating a separate auxillary function; it essentially ends up looking like the `filter` example I gave.

Comment: But then the top level function would not be recursive, would it?

Answer (score 0):

Start with a for loop (it's easier to think about):

```
def disjunctive_union(a, b):
    a_filt = [x for x in a if x not in b]
    b_filt = [x for x in b if x not in a]
    return a_filt + b_filt
```

Let's make this "recursive". One idea is to remove elements we've already checked and call our function on a smaller list.

```
def disjunctive_union(a, b):
    if len(a) == 0:
        return b

    first = a[0]
    if first not in b:
        return [first] + disjunctive_union(a[1:], b)

    # These filters can individually be made recursive too
    # (and often are in functional languages!)
    a = [x for x in a if x != first]
    b = [x for x in b if x != first]

    return disjunctive_union(a, b)
```

---

EDIT: To demonstrate a recursive variant of the filters:

```
 a = [x for x in a if x != first]
```

can be replaced with:

```
def recursive_filter(pred, xs):
    x = next(xs)
    if pred(x):
        yield x
    yield from recursive_filter(pred, xs)

a = list(recursive_filter(lambda x: x != first, iter(a)))
```

---

EDIT 2: I thought about it a bunch and here's a simpler solution:

```
def disjunctive_union(a, b):
    a_filt = list(recursive_filter(lambda x: x not in b, iter(a)))
    b_filt = list(recursive_filter(lambda x: x not in a, iter(b)))
    return a_filt + b_filt
```

...using the `recursive_filter` I defined above.

(FWIW, I think this whole thing is kind of a pointless exercise in making a non-recursive function recursive...)

Comment: Can't really use for :|

Comment: I've tried it and -> disjoint_union([2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3]) -> gives me only -> [5]

Comment: @KellyBaptista Try again -- I fixed a minor typo when it used to be (incorrectly) called `disjoint_union`

Answer (score 0):

Hi here is one more solution.

```
def diff(l1,l2):
    result=[]
    if len(l1)==0:
    #return l2, finally it will only contain unique elements (if any)
            return l2
    if l1[0] in l2:
        copy=l1[0]
    #remove all occurances of the common element from both lists
        l1=list(filter(lambda a: a != l1[0], l1))
        l2=list(filter(lambda a: a != copy, l2))
    else:
    #if list1's first element is not in list2 add it to result and pop it
        result.append(l1[0])
        l1.pop(0)
    result+=diff(l1,l2)
    return result

list1=[1,3,2,4,4,5]
list2=[1,2,7]
print(diff(list1,list2))
```

Output:

[3, 4, 4, 5, 7]

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
def compare(a, b, original_a = None, original_b = None):
    result = []

    if original_a is None:
        original_a = a
    if original_b is None:
        original_b = b

    if a and a[0] not in original_b:
        result.append(a[0])

    if b and b[0] not in original_a:
        result.append(b[0])

    if a or b:
        result += compare(a[1:], b[1:], original_a, original_b)

    return result
```

Comment: compare([2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3]) -> gives me [[4, 5], [5]] instead of [4, 5]

Comment: oops, I had a typo

Comment: It works if I do compare([2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3]) -> [4, 5]

Comment: But if compare([2, 3, 4, 5], [4, 5]) -> [2, 3, 4, 5]

Comment: You're right. I see why. Are you allowed to add keyword arguments to the function?

Comment: I think so, teacher doesn´t really say in the homework if I can or not. So I think there's no problem

Comment: I think I have another (better) idea. Give me a moment to try it out.

Comment: By the way, I also edited this answer to give the correct output.